# Bash about repeat until

Tags: bash, shell, unix

I want to know about that syntax is correct or not. I cant test it right now sorry, but its important for me. Its an FTP script. The file name is `a.txt`, I would like to create a script that will upload a file until it is successful. It will works or not? Anyone can help me to build the correct one pls

```
LOGFILE=/home/transfer_logs/$a.log
DIR=/home/send
Search=`ls /home/send`
firstline=`egrep "Connected" $LOGFILE`
secondline=`egrep "File successfully transferred" $LOGFILE`

if [ -z "$Search" ]; then
cd $DIR
ftp -p -v -i 192.163.3.3 < ../../example.script > ../../$LOGFILE 2>&1
fi

if
egrep "Not connected" $LOGFILE; then
repeat
ftp -p -v -i 192.163.3.3 < ../../example.script > ../../$LOGFILE 2>&1
until
[[ -n $firstline && $secondline ]]; 
done
fi
```

example.script contains:

```
 binary
 mput a.txt
 quit
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does `ftp` not return a reasonable result?  It would be easiest to write:

```
while ! ftp ...; do sleep 1; done
```

If you insist on searching the log file, do something like:

```
while :; do
    ftp ... > $LOGFILE
    grep -qF "File successfully transferred" $LOGFILE && break
done
```

Or

```
while ! test -e $LOGFILE || grep -qF "Not connected" $LOGFILE; do
    ftp ... > $LOGFILE
done
```

Comment: @Smithis I do not understand your question.

Comment: I would like to create a script that will upload a file until it is successful

Comment: Have you tried either of the loops given in my answer?  If so, are they not working?  If not, what is the error?

Comment: as i said i cant test is right now, im in hospital using my notpad:) just interested it will works or not. But seems not so im in trouble:)

Answer (score 2):

> It will works or not?

No, it won't work. According to [§3.2.4.1 "Looping Constructs" of the *Bash Reference Manual*](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Looping-Constructs), these are the kinds of loops that exist:

```
until test-commands; do consequent-commands; done

while test-commands; do consequent-commands; done

for name [ [in [words …] ] ; ] do commands; done

for (( expr1 ; expr2 ; expr3 )) ; do commands ; done
```

You'll notice that none of them begins with `repeat`.

Additionally, these two lines:

```
firstline=`egrep "Connected" $LOGFILE`
secondline=`egrep "File successfully transferred" $LOGFILE`
```

run `egrep` *immediately*, and set their variables accordingly. This command:

```
[[ -n $firstline && $secondline ]]
```

will always give the same return-value, because nothing in the loop will ever modify `$firstline` and `$secondline`. You need to actually put an `egrep` command inside the loop.

Comment: @Smithis: You can't test your script; therefore, you can't build it. (A script doesn't count as "built" unless it actually works!)